# GA Goal destination by specific text on site index page

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

In my case start page = goal page = home page of site. Site Goal is when user go to billing page first, pay and then finally redirected back to home index with message, like: "Now you are premium user..". Site is multi-language, this messages are different for different surfers locales. I was add special hidden code tag to script **html** for all who complete payment, like `<!-- now_you_are_premium -->`. Looks like then I can track goal by this text keyword on same index page. If this **keyword is exist** on home page, **Goal is achieved.**

Question: If it possible, how to setup GA Goal which reacting on text is equals to some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to redirect the user back to the home page with a URL parameter:

```
http://example.com/?now-premium
```

Adding a URL parameter to the URL usually shows the same content, but creates a different URL that can be used as a destination goal in Google Analytics.

A different solution would be to send an [event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) from the home page when the user is a new premium user.  The code that puts the message onto the page could also add some JavaScript to the page like:

```
<script>ga('send', 'event', 'membership', 'now-premium', 'User 123');</script>
```

Then you could create a goal based on that event.  The downside to event based goals is they can't be used in the funnel visualization.  Only destination URL based goals can be part of a funnel visualization in Google Analatycis.

Comment: Is a Google Analytics tracking code is sensitive for difference of URLs like `http://example.com/?some` or `http://example.com/?another`? I mean it is trckable for GA in case this pages have same content for different URI..

Comment: Google Analytics is by default sensitive to URLs whose only difference is query string.  It is possible to customize GA with filters to striip parameters that don't change the page https://edit.co.uk/blog/how-to-handle-url-query-parameters-google-analytics/ but then you lose the ability to use parameters for tracking tricks like the one I propose.